# Sitecore WFFM- get all dropouts data programmatically

Tags: mongodb, sitecore-query

We have the requirement like, pull the all dropout users information and send email to our client.

I know that WFFM captures form dropout data, but how to get this data pro-grammatically,I check with mongoDB **"FormData"** Collection, but am not able get the exact drop out data, please suggest if any API's are available.

I refereed below article , didn't get the solution-

[WFFM Analytics - is it possible to report on dropouts by field?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/820/wffm-analytics-is-it-possible-to-report-on-dropouts-by-field)

actually we need to run the scheduler and prepare the excel sheet with all the drop out users data and send an email  on daily basis.

**Note:** we are using Sitecore 8.2 update 3 and Mongo Db 3.4 version.

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: This is more of a "how do I query MongoDB" question. Maybe the answer here will get you started; else I suggest StackOverflow for a plain "how do I query this data programmatically?".  https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5354/how-to-join-mongodb-collections-using-sitecore-mongo-db-report-data-source

Comment: Thanks Mark Cassidy, my concern is how can we identify the form data is drop out  data in mongo DB "Form Data" collection, is there any property available?

Comment: No clue mate, sorry. But if you document your initial steps, and isolate  your question to exactly this - it would make for a great SSE question that would be welcomed.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to get the dropouts data using site-core API.

Comment: None that I know of